# SharePoint 2010 document library upload fails for particular user - doc already exists with same name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a  SharePoint 2010 document library in a publishing site (with workflow - standard approval) that does not have any custom code running in it. It is just configured with OOTB features - Metadata Service tagging, versioning (no checkout required, uploading to add as new versions for existing files, adds each version as a new major version), SharePoint Search etc. Only thing not OOTB is setting up of a PDF iFilter as the library stores PDFs.

Other users can upload new versions of documents with no issues, but one user (who has approver rights across the site collection) cannot. Each time he tries to upload a newer version of a document to the library he gets an error message:

The specified name is already in use.  The document or folder name was not changed.  To change the name to a different value, close this dialog and edit the properties of the document or folder.

Checking the SP log files with the correlation ID does not really show much, beyond this exception:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified name is already in use.  The document or folder name was not changed.  To change the name to a different value, close this dialog and edit the properties of the document or folder.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)

Comment: you should format your exception text as code so it can be read better

Comment: How does user upload document? Is here checking "Upload as new version" flag?

Comment: Yes, the upload as new version flag is set by default. Leonidas- I will clean stack trace